# "Not having had time" or "not having time"?

Tags: phrase-usage

A fiction about CYBORG,

> **Not having had time** to connect it to her wired nervous system, she
>   felt like she was dragging around a paperweight.

Why is here not "not having time"?

Comment: Can you include the line before and after this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

*Not having had time* = the not having occurred earlier than the feeling.
*Not having time* = the not having and the feeling occurred simultaneously.

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!